# JavaFX FadeTransistion causes enormous CPU load

Tags: java, performance, javafx

Have a simple rectangle inside a HBox (container) nested in a scrollpane.
This rectangle has the following transition applied:

```
attentionRectangle = new Rectangle(1, 1, container.getWidth(), container.getHeight());
attentionRectangle.setManaged(false);

attentionRectangle.setFill(Color.LIME);

attentionRectangleTransition = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(3000), attentionRectangle);
attentionRectangleTransition.setFromValue(0.2);
attentionRectangleTransition.setToValue(0.8);
                    attentionRectangleTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
attentionRectangleTransition.setAutoReverse(true);

attentionRectangleTransition.play();
```

Now the following behavior can be noticed and reproduced (in my project at least):
 1. If the scrollpane is completely empty, the CPU-load of the java machine is at ~1%
 2. If the element with the blinking rectangle is alone inside the scrollpane, the CPU-load by Java is around 3-4%
 3. If other simple elements yet without the blinking one is inside the scrollpane, the cpu load is around 2-3%
 4. If the simple elements AND the blinking one is inside the scrollpane, the CPU-load rockets to 15-17% which is pretty much a fully loaded virtual thread (due to 8 available threads on my machine).

Well, is this normal?
Or does someone have a suggestion how to improve?

Would be really thankful.

Console output if executed with "-Dprism.verbose=true":

```
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw 
Using native-based Pisces rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
    succeeded.
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
OS Information:
    Windows version 10.0 build 16299
D3D Driver Information:
    Radeon (TM) RX 480 Graphics
    \\.\DISPLAY1
    Driver aticfx32.dll, version 22.19.677.257
    Pixel Shader version 3.0
    Device : ven_1002, dev_67DF, subsys_94801682
    Max Multisamples supported: 4
 vsync: true vpipe: true

Loading Prism common native library ...
    succeeded.
PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: LinearConvolveShadow_8
PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: LinearConvolveShadow_16
PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: LinearConvolveShadow_12
PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: LinearConvolveShadow_4

PPSRenderer: scenario.effect - createShader: LinearConvolveShadow_20
```

The last line happens when the animation starts!

Comment: What OS and hardware are you running this on? Could you include the output when running with `java -Dprism.verbose=true` (to see which render pipeline is used)?

Comment: @sillyfly Thank you kindly for the answer!
Working on Win 10 on an intel Haswel e3 1230v3 and a Radeon RX 480.

Will add the verbose result to the question!